# how to transfer header for soap request in soapui?

Tags: testing, header, automation, soapui

I have 2 requests

Request1 will generate a unique id every time and then I want to use this id  in Request2 Header

How can I transfer this automatically?

Thanks

Comment: **Request1 generate unique id** - Do you mean unique id is part of Request1's response?

Comment: You will need to provide a lot more information. Sample Request, what exactly is it you want to transfer from where. Have a look at [ask]. Also, check the links along the right side, under "Related".

Answer (score 0):

`var1=YourUniqueID`

Then add header to your request like this or use a variation of this

```
getAllHttpSteps=testRunner.testCase.getTestStepsOfType(com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.teststeps.RestTestRequestStep)
    for (step in getAllHttpSteps){
        def headers = new StringToStringMap() //Use StringToStringMap Object to store headers key/value.
         headers.put("header field","$var1")
        //add more header fields if require
         step.testRequest.setRequestHeaders(headers) //setting header in request
    }
```

Comment: Adding custom headers is a built-in function of SoapUI. https://www.soapui.org/soap-and-wsdl/headers-and-attachments.html#1-Custom-HTTP-Headers I do not understand why you would do this using scripts.

Comment: @SiKing I need this because I want to transfer value automatically. This is not a static value. Request 1 generates Unique ID every time and every time I don't want to copy from Request 1: Response and put into Request 2.

Comment: @Pooja The `Value` in the custom header can a property expansion, such as what you are trying to describe.

Answer (score 0):

Groovy Script : I have store unique id as response and (use getdata from response of Request 1) . testRunner.testCase.setPropertyValue("GValue", response) and

in Request2 : Header name UniqueId and Header Value : ${#TestCase#GValue}